# With wp_list_category put every existing category into an option tag

Tags: html, categories

Like the title says, I'm using wp_list_categories to get all of the existing categories of my website listed. I would like to achieve this:

```
<select class="filters-select">
   <option value=".category1">category1</option>
   <option value=".category2">category2</option>
   <option value=".category3">category3</option>
   ...
</select>
```

I'm not sure how the code has to be to achieve that structure, so far I have this which it's not working but at least it's not li's inside a ul anymore, it also just shows all of the categories twice, I need some kind of foreeach but that's beyond my knowledge:

```
             <?php $args = array(
                'hide_empty'         => 0,
                'orderby'            => 'name',
                'order'              => 'ASC',
                'show_count'         => 0,
                'use_desc_for_title' => 0,
                'title_li'           => 0,
                'style'              => '',
                'echo'               => false
              );
              $cats = wp_list_categories($args);

              if ( $cats ) {
                  echo '<option value=".'.$cats.'">'.$cats.'</option>'; 
          } ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wp_list_categories()` isn't the right function for this kind of output, as that is meant for displaying `<ul>` lists.

Instead you should be looking at [`get_categories()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_categories/), that instead only gets all the info about the categories and doesn't apply any formatting to it.

For your desired output you can use something like this:

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'hide_empty' => 0,
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'order' => 'ASC',
);
$cats = get_categories($args);

if ( $cats ) {
    echo '<select class="filters-select">'; //echo the select

    //loop through each category and echo as option for the select
    foreach ($cats as $cat) { 
        echo '<option value="'. $cat->slug .'">'. $cat->cat_name .'</option>';
    }

    echo '</select>'; //close the select
}
?>
```

Comment: Very nice, it works perfectly.